# ПРЯНУТЬ и УПРЯЖЬ - однокоренные слова?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Являются ли однокоренными слова *прянуть* (двигаться) и *упряжь*?

Comment: @Михаил Кумыш, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас нет, значения корней разошлись, а исторически да. Упряжь - совокупность предметов для запряжки лошадей от - пряж - прягу, тяну, стягиваю (спряжение сюда же).

Прянуть - прыгать, скакать. прядать (ушами) - встряхивать, прыгать, пружинить, пружина. Даже пруд - некогда значил "поток, быстрое течение", уже потом появилось "запруда".

Так что все эти корни восходят к древнему корню -пре- (е - следствие носового согл.) -натягивать, напирать, с силой распрямляться.

Answer (score 0):

Оба произошли от ПИЕ корня "(s)pregh-" - прыгать, спешить.